# ¿Cómo enviar como parametro una struct?

Tags: c, struct

Tengo la siguiente struct en mi función Main:

```
struct configurando{
    int fixedMatrix;
    int messyMatrix;
    bool used;
    char boardGame[4];
    char coords[4];
} base[filas][columnas];
```

Y quería enviarla a otra función, y las maneras que probé fueron:

```
void hard(struct *base);
```

O también

```
void hard(*base);
```

O

```
void hard(configurando *base);
```

Sin embargo sigue marcandome errores, ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de redactarlo? Y también ¿Qué le debo enviar, a 'base' o a 'configurando'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tu quieres que una función reciba un entero escribes algo tal que:

```
void func(int);
```

En vez de:

```
void func(a);
```

Es decir, a la función le dices **el tipo** de dato que va a recibir.

Con las estructuras pasa lo mismo. Solo que en este caso el tipo es un poco más largo.

```
struct configurando{
    int fixedMatrix;
    int messyMatrix;
    bool used;
    char boardGame[4];
    char coords[4];
} base[filas][columnas];
```

Para este caso concreto el tipo es

```
struct configurando
```

Luego la función habrá que declararla así:

```
void hard(struct configurando * XXX);
```

Reemplazando XXX por el nombre que le quieras dar a la variable dentro de la función.

A modo de recomendación final, yo modificaría el nombre de la estructura. `configurando` es una acción, y una estructura ... son datos, no acciones. Las acciones le corresponderían en tal caso a las funciones, pero es que en C las estructuras no pueden tener funciones ...

Comment: Gracias, le había puesto configurando de nombre porque no se me había ocurrido algo más, pero en realidad no ejerce ninguna función, solo ucupaba múltiples matrices para trabajar. Seguiré tu recomendación